# How To Correctly Extend the Sprite Class in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently pursuing game development as a hobby, and have run into what seems to be a conflict in my mind regarding how to properly (using best practices) extend the `Sprite` class in LibGDX (or for the sake of this question, any Sprite class).

### What I Would Like To Do

I would like to to create a class, `Ship.java`, with the constructor as follows:

```
// Note the lack of a Texture object in the constructor here
public Ship(float startingX, float startingY){

    super(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/ship_texture.png")), 0, 0);

    this.startingX = startingX;
    this.startingY = startingY;

}
```

### Why I Can't Do This

First, this implementation forces me to forfeit having a reference to the `Texture` that I am passing into the super constructor.  This means that I cannot properly `dispose()` it later, which would lead to memory leaks later in the code.

### The Problem

Since the constructor of the `Sprite` class forces you to specify a `Texture`, and I would want a `Ship` to *always* have the same `Texture` (thus would not want to specify it in the constructor of a `Ship`), I am limited to hacking together some factory method to construct the `Ship`.

### My Current Solution

As specified above, I currently have a factory method that creates the `Ship` instead of using the constructor.

### The Code

Below I have detailed the code I am currently using to get the `Ship` class instantiated.  Please feel free to critique it:

```
// Private constructor because I do not want this method to be called ever
private Ship(Texture texture, int row, int column) {

    // Calls the super constructor (for the Sprite class)
    super(texture, row, column);
}

// Instead, this create method returns a new instance of Ship   
public static Ship create(int row, int column){

    // Create the new texture
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/ship.png"));

    // Set the LINEAR filter (might switch to NEAREST later)
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    // Return a new instance of the Ship
    return new Ship(texture, row, column);
}
```

### Why I Don't Like This Solution

I feel as though this is a very "hacky" fix, as it defeats the purpose of a constructor, and although static factory methods are good practice, I don't think it should be necessary to implement a new factory method for each object I plan to draw on the `Screen`.

---

### My Question

What is the best way to extend the `Sprite` class (thus keeping all the helper methods that it provides), and still define the `Texture` that will be displayed on the object within the constructor of the `Ship`?

Is the current approach I am using appropriate?

Comment: Not really an answer but I'd like to hear why you choose to extend the Sprite class in the first place? In our last game I had classes that *had* sprites, because I wanted each thing to be able draw itself - a base class called DrawableThing had a reference to a Texture or Sprite and a Draw method that took a SpriteBatch - but I didn't subclass directly from Sprite. Not criticizing your method, it honestly hadn't occurred to me. What are the pros/cons of your way vs my way?

Comment: After reviewing my circumstances, it actually does make more sense to simply include a `Sprite` in the class.  Extending it would not really be necessary.

The reason I chose to extend it was because I just wanted a Sprite that had maybe one more function, and didn't see the need for an entire new class.

Comment: Upon review, however, it makes sense that I could get this same functionality if I just added a `Sprite` into my class.  

This consideration makes my question sound silly, but hey, I learned something nonetheless!

Comment: it's this kind of stuff that can keep me up at night weighing the pros and cons of certain methods. what i love about indie gaming is that there's no wrong answer. if it works, it works.

Comment: This is precisely my problem.  I always spend hours working on "best practices" instead of just getting something to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the game I'm developing I'm using a centralized [AssetManager](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager), which will hold the references and automatically dispose them. I just need to load the [pack](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker) file and get the TextureAtlas from it. (or the texture if you are using single images instead of packs)

```
TextureAtlas atlas = game.assets.get("filename.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
jewelSprite = new JewelSprite(jewelType, atlas.findRegion("textureName")), game); 
// use `AtlasRegion` instead of `Texture`
```

Check the first link for a nice overview of the AssetManager. You don't need to pack the textures but it is recommended for performance.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  I will look into this immediately and get back to you!

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be a package geared towards making the loading of `Texture`s easier and more streamlined, which does not help me here as I am not running into issues loading the `Texture`, but rather, *when* and *how* to load it.  Did I maybe miss something in the link you provided that would relate more to my post?

Comment: @Squagem Well, using the manager to load the texture you won't need to create, or dispose it yourself, which I understood as being the problem. You just call `manager.get("data/mytexture.png", Texture.class)` to access it. If you sure you don't need a texture anymore just call `manager.unload("texture.png").

Comment: Ahh yes, I see.  Okay, this seems like it would be a solution.  Yet again, however, this is quite a bit of overhead just to extend the `Sprite` class.  The tutorial even specified, that if you only have a few `Texture`s as I do, that using the `AssetsManager` was a bad idea.  However, nonetheless, it solves my issue.  I will leave the question unanswered for a while to hear some other potential approaches, but after a day or two you will receive your accept! (Assuming a more lightweight approach is not found) :)